# Error: The term 'root' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a PowerShell script which when run directly on the server works just fine. But when I try to run the same from an Azure pipeline, it is giving the error as below:

UpdateConfigFile : The term 'root' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
UpdateConfigFile -clockIpAddress $ClockIP
CategoryInfo  : ObjectNotFound: (root:String) [UpdateConfigFile]

The full yml file is as below:

```
trigger: none
pr: none
parameters:
  - name: environmentGroup
    displayName: EnvrionmentGroup
    type: object
    default: Enter Environment Group
  - name: environmentTag
    displayName: EnvironmentTag
    type: string
    default: Enter your tag
stages:
  - stage: RecongfigureClock
    jobs:
      - deployment: RecongfigureClock
        environment:
          name: "${{ parameters.environmentGroup }}"
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: "${{ parameters.environmentTag }}"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  displayName: Update Store Clock GT4
                  inputs:
                    targetType: inline
                    script: |
                      function IsClockAlive {
                          [CmdletBinding()]
                          param (
                              [string]$IPAddress
                          )
                          return Test-Connection $IPAddress -Quiet
                      }

                      function UpdateClockConfiguration {
                          param (
                              [string]$ClockIP
                          )

                          if (Test-ClockSSHConnection -clockIpAddress $ClockIP) {
                            UpdateConfigFile -clockIpAddress $ClockIP
                          }
                          else {
                            throw "[ERROR] Cannot SSH into the clock"
                          }
                      }

                      function UpdateConfigFile {
                          [CmdletBinding()]
                          param (
                              [string]$clockIpAddress
                          )

                          $ComputerName = $clockIpAddress
                          $SysAdminSqlServerLogin = "$(SysAdminSqlServerLogin)"
                          $SysAdminSqlServerCurrentPassword = "$(SysAdminSqlServerCurrentPassword)"
                          $hostname = $(hostname)

                          $GT4Password = $(GT4Pass)
                          $GT4User = $(GT4user)
                          $Command = "appcfgset clksrv_host " + $hostname

                          $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $GT4Password -AsPlainText -Force
                          $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($GT4User, $secpasswd)

                          $SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials

                          Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $SessionID.Sessionid -Command $Command
                      }


                      function GetClockIP {
                          [CmdletBinding()]
                          param (
                              [string]$FinalOctlet
                          )

                          $computername = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($Null).HostName
                          $machine = Test-Connection $computername -count 1
                          $octets = $machine.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString -split "\."
                          $octets[3] = $FinalOctlet
                          $newaddress = $octets -join "."

                          return $newaddress
                      }


                      function Test-ClockSSHConnection([string]$clockIpAddress){
                          for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
                              Write-Host "Trying to set SSH connection to clock $clockIpAddress - Try $i"
                              
                              if (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $clockIpAddress -Port 22 -InformationLevel Quiet) {
                                  return $true
                              }
                              else {
                                  Write-Host "SSH connection to clock failed. Trying again"
                                  start-sleep -m 6000 
                              }        
                          }
                      }

                      $clockOne=GetClockIP 91
                        
                      if (IsClockAlive -IPAddress $clockOne) {
                        UpdateClockConfiguration `
                            -ClockIP $clockOne `
                            -Verbose
                        Write-Output "| Successfully updated the Clock with IP" $clockOne 
                      }
```

Please help.

Comment: Change `$GT4User = $(GT4user)` to `$GT4User = "$(GT4user)"` (repeat for any other string variable macro not passed as a command argument)

Comment: Wow. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, that solved the problem. How can I set your comment as the answer?

Comment: You're most welcome! I've posted a proper answer below, you should be able to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon outlined to the left of it :)

Comment: That is not a [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) file (which is an XML derivative and looks completely different), but the more recently developed YAML format. Please note that the officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since September 2006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Azure pipeline variable macro expressions (`$(variableName)`) are expanded before PowerShell is invoked, so a statement like:

```
$GT4User = $(GT4user)
```

Looks like this by the time PowerShell evaluates it:

```
$GT4User = root
```

The bareword token `root` is then interpreted as a command name, leading to the error message you see.

Fix the problem by quoting the macro expressions in the pipeline definition:

```
# now it'll come out as `$GT4User = 'root'`
$GT4User = '$(GT4user)'
```

Repeat for any other variable macro that's meant to be passed as a string literal